# Альтернативные возможность публикации постов пользователями

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовывается в WordPress возможность предоставления авторизованным пользователям ранга "Автор" функции создавать и публиковать посты (`posts`)? Насколько это безопасно? *установил плагин [Ultimate Member](https://ultimatemember.com/), но там что-то функции этой пока не обнаружил. Поделитесь своим опытом

Comment: Такая возможность есть из коробки. Изучи уже ВП.

Comment: Про вход через /wp-admin/ и дальше в Посты известно, интересует, какие-то более кастомные варианты? Насколько вообще, это безопасно, давать возможность создания.

Comment: Что значит "более кастомные варианты"? Что бы что? Ты спрашивал "как юзерам публиковать посты". Ответ - это есть из коробки. Если тебя интересует что-то другое - так про это и спрашивай. А безопасность... тут проблема не столько техническая (очевидно что со стороны ВП безопасно. Но что ещё наставит/накостылит  "админ"- большой вопрос). сколько юридическая.

Comment: приведу пример сайт - `https://wp-kama.ru/` написан на WP. Есть возможность задавать Вопросы, зарегистрированым пользователям, но при этом ни каких взаимодействий с админкой сайта автор не дает, вопрос - почему автор выбрал такое решение... он же что-то явно знает. Других примеров WP сайтов с возможностью создавать полноценный контент как-то не попадалось. Все что-то самопальное делают...

Comment: Давай попробую ещё раз: это уже ДРУГОЙ вопрос. Да и собственно рассуждения на тему "почему" это не формате SO. Тут FaQ-сервис, а не форум.